# Как реалозовать добавление выпадающего списка

Tags: yii2

Есть выпадающий список

```
<?= $form->field($catSerial, 'id_cat')->dropDownList($cat,['prompt' => 'Выбирите категорию']); ?>
```

возникла необходимость реализовать возможность добавлять такие же списки, следующим образом:
По клику условно говоря на любую ссылку(с допустим id="dropbox") создается новый   такой же выпадающий список;
Это  нужно для того что бы страница могла  отображаться в двух или более  категориях;
Конкретно этот выпадающий список выводит количество категорий из базы.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно такое реализовать в Yii2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для моих целей очень хорошо подошел вот этот плагин yii2-widget-select2 расположенный по этому [адресу](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) позволяет делать множественный выбор

Answer (score 0):

Выпадающий список в Yii2 можно реализовать следующими способами:

```
<?php
$data = Table::find()->all();
echo $form->field($catSerial, 'id_cat')->DropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name'), ['prompt' => 'Выберите значение', 'class' => 'form-control']);
?>
```

или

```
<?php 
$data = Table::find()->all();
echo Html::activeDropDownList($catSerial, 'id_cat', ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name'), ['prompt' => 'Выберите значение', 'class' => 'form-control']); 
?>
```

Где **Table** - название вашей таблицы. 
Формируется массив, с ключем равным полю **id** и значением равным полю **name**

Comment: Не думайте что я пытаюсь Вас обидеть ? но вы читали мой вопрос. Как формировать выпадающий список из таблицы я знаю мне надо добавить возможность добавлять их налету.